# Проблемы при парсинге объектов через GSON

Tags: java, gson

Доброе время суток.

Сейчас пишу парсер для API Codeforces
там есть метод `contest.hacks`, который возвращает список из объектов Hack

Так вот, на любой запрос API отвечает объектом, состоящим из трёх полей: статус, комментарий (если статус `FAILED`) и результат (если статус `OK`). Вот, собственно, что там внутри:

[image: Imgur]

И сам метод `process(String)`, который заполняет все поля:

```
public void process(String query) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(query);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String json = br.readLine();
            Type type = new TypeToken<CFAnswer<T>>() {}.getType();
            CFAnswer<T> answer = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
            status = answer.status;
            comment = answer.comment;
            result = answer.result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Создание объекта: `CFAnswer<List<Hack>> ans = new CFAnswer<>();`
Проблема в том, что вместо списка объектов Hack он мне возвращает список объектов `LinkedTreeMap`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure). Все эти generic-типы подставляются и существуют только в момент компиляции, что позволяет вам убедиться в [типобезопасности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) вашего кода.

На самом же деле во время исполнения программы для jvm не существует `List<T>`. Есть только `List`.

Из-за этого gson-овский [`TypeToken`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) позволяет получить только литерал типа, т.е. именно тот тип, который был объявлен. Если объявите `CFAnswer<T>` - gson будет считать что это именно `CFAnswer<T>`, а не `CFAnswer<List<Hack>>`, который существовал только в момент статической проверки типов на этапе компиляции.

В вашем случае я бы сделал так. В класс `CFAnswer` добавил статический factory-метод, принимающий параметром готовый экземпляр `TypeToken`:

```
public static <T> CFAnswer process(String query, TypeToken<CFAnswer<T>> token) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(query);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String json = br.readLine();

    Type type = token.getType();
    CFAnswer<T> answer = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
    return answer;
}
```

Сторона, вызывающая этот метод, должна знать, что она ожидает получить:

```
CFAnswer<List<Hack>> cfAnswer1 = CFAnswer.process(json, new TypeToken<CFAnswer<List<Hack>>>(){});
```

---

*<sub>PS. На самом деле я вру. На вашем месте я бы взял какой-нибудь генератор для REST-клиента типа [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) и не маялся.</sub>*